# jQuerify Grease Monkey script not working for jQuery dependent scripts on page?

Tags: jquery, dom, greasemonkey, frontend

I have a simple `$(document).ready(function(){});` on the page that can't access the jQuery library.

I would normally just put the library on the page, but it's a part of a backend "edit" page within a CMS.  I really just need the jQuery library to be loaded before the rest of the scripts fire off so I can make a few small changes until Sunday when we are able to actually fix this issue the right way (removing these scripts is not an option right now my only option is to find a way to get grease monkey jQuerify to work).  Any ideas?

**Clarification**

I need to "jQuerify" a page I'm viewing, but instead of doing it after the DOM is loaded.. I need it to load as if it were in the header of the page so that any dependent scripts will run properly.  Is this possible?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via the [`@run-at  document-start`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) meta-rule. The script is then executed before the document root is even constructed.

The script below keeps running an interval, until either `document.documentElement` (`<html>`) or `document.head` (`<head>`) exists. Then, it injects jQuery.

I have confirmed that the code is working using this **fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VuJjT/show/** (when the Userscript is not active, it shows `undefined` 2x, otherwise, it shows `function` 2x).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           jQuery before everything
// @namespace      Rob W
// @description    Inject jQuery as soon as possible, before start
// @include        *
// @run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==


var s = document.createElement('script');
s.onload = function() {
    // Clean-up
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
var poller = setInterval(function() {
    var insertInto = document.head || document.documentElement;
    if (insertInto) {              // `<html>` or `<head>` exists
        clearInterval(poller);     // Clear poller
        insertInto.appendChild(s); // Inject script.
    };
}, 4); // Every 4 milliseconds. This interval may run a few times.
```

Comment: Note that this is not foolproof.  It is possible that early script nodes will fire before this does.  Tests show that even the ["zero delay", timer workarounds](http://ajaxian.com/archives/settimeout-delay) are not always fast enough with Firefox.

Comment: @BrockAdams `@run-at document-start` causes the code to execute before the construction of the document. I have tested the code + demo several times, without any misses (FF 11).

Comment: Yes it does.  But the gap between when the document becomes detectable to GM and when the first doc script fires can mean that the GM injection happens too late for that first script or two, depending on the document.  I've seen this "in the wild" which is why I mentioned it.  If I feel frisky, I'll rig a demo page (no promises).